# How to use DeprecationLevel.ERROR

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I am writing a library and have a class that looks something like this (contrived example, but shows self reference:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger

class MyClass(private val myNum: Int) {

  companion object {
    private val LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass::class.java.canonicalName)
  }

  constructor() : this(1337)

  fun addTo(num: Int): Int  {
    LOG.fine { "Adding num $num to $myNum" }
    return myNum + num
  }

  fun doubleAdd(num: Int): Int = 2 * addTo(num)
}
```

Now, I have decided that I want to deprecate this class and have my consumers move on to to better things, so I give them a warning.

```
@Deprecated("Don't use!", level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING)
class MyClass(private val myNum: Int) {
  // ...
}
```

Now, after some more time I'd like to increase the strictness with my deprecation. I still want the library to be binary compatible, so I do not remove the code I see that there is the `DeprecationLevel.ERROR` available, so I try to use it.

```
@Deprecated("Don't use!", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
class MyClass(private val myNum: Int) {
  // ...
}
```

Except now, when I try to compile my own project, I get compiler errors:

```
e: /path/to/project/src/main/kotlin/MyClass.kt: (7, 44): Using 'MyClass' is an error. Don't use!                                                               
e: /path/to/project/src/main/kotlin/MyClass.kt: (10, 23): Using 'MyClass' is an error. Don't use!
```

This is on both the `MyClass` reference and the `this` primary constructor reference.

What is the point of `DeprecationLevel.ERROR`? If I am using it wrong, what is the intended use, and how do I use it?

**NOTE**: This whole example was done with Kotlin `1.2.21`

Answer (score 2):

It does exactly what is described in the documentation: [DeprecationLevel](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecation-level/)

`ERROR` means usage of that code generates an error in the compiler. This is when you know using the code is going to cause problems and you'd rather crash the compilation, even if that code compiled fine previously.

There is also the `HIDDEN` deprecation level which does what you describe. It 'hides' the annotated element from the compiler but leaves it in the binary output. This will still cause a compilation error in your project because it is meant for binary compatibility, not newly compiled code.

Comment: I still get a compiler error on the `MyClass::class.java.canonicalName` usage with `Using 'MyClass' is an error. Don't use!` in the same class. My desired behavior, or at least what I would expect, is that the module/package/library unit itself can still make use of it (maybe with a compiler flag) but consuming libraries are warned or fail when they try and consume it. I may be thinking about this in the wrong way, though.

Comment: `Deprecation` should only be used if usage is discouraged regardless of source. What you're looking for seems to be the `internal` visibility modifier. This restricts access to classes within the same module. (Although I believe this cannot be enforced in Java due to limitations of the JVM)